# How to pass value of dropdown from .aspx to .asmx.cs?

Tags: asp.net, asmx

I have this dropdown on my p1.aspx:

```
<select id="ListBoxViewType" style="width:160px;font-family:Tahoma;visibility:hidden;">
                        <option value="Amendment">Amendment</option>
                        <option value="Agreement">Full Terms Amendment</option>
                        <option value="Both">Both</option>
                    </select>
```

and i need to get its value on p2.asmx.cs:

```
if ( <insert something like this: ListBoxViewType.Value=="Amendment">)
                            {
                                fileName = chReadData.ContractNumber +"_Amendment" +"-" + chReadData.DisplaySupplementNumber;
                                description = "Amendment for " + chReadData.ContractNumber + "-" + chReadData.DisplaySupplementNumber + " (\"" + chReadData.ContractDescription + "\")";
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                fileName = chReadData.ContractNumber +"_Full_Amendment" +"-" + chReadData.DisplaySupplementNumber;
                                description = "Amendment for " + chReadData.ContractNumber + "-" + chReadData.DisplaySupplementNumber + " (\"" + chReadData.ContractDescription + "\")";
                            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `runat="server"` to your select element:

```
<select id="ListBoxViewType" runat="server" style="width:160px;font-family:Tahoma;visibility:hidden;">
                    <option value="Amendment">Amendment</option>
                    <option value="Agreement">Full Terms Amendment</option>
                    <option value="Both">Both</option>
                </select>
```

And to get the selected value you can use:

```
this.ListBoxViewType.SelectedIndex
```

---

Additionally you should consider using a `DropDownList` control instead:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ListBoxViewType" runat="server"....
```

And to access the selected items:

```
this.ListBoxViewType.SelectedValue
this.ListBoxViewType.SelectedItem.Text
this.ListBoxViewType.SelectedItem.Value
```